# Breadth first search in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a representation of a tree using lists.
For example:

```
(1 ((2 (3)) (3 (2)))) (2 ((1 (3)) (3 (1)))) (3 ((1 (2)) (2 (1)))))`
```

Now I need to traverse it level by level while maintaining the hierarchy tree. For instance:

1. Traversing **root node** `(1)`
2. Traversing **depth 1** `(1 2) (1 3) (2 1) (3 1) (3 1) (3 2)`
3. Traversing **depth 2** `(1 2 3) (1 3 2) (2 1 3) (2 3 1) (3 1 2) (3 2 1)`

I can't figure out how to do it in Lisp. Any help (even a pseudo code) is appreciated. I have thought of several approaches but none of them seems legit.

Comment: How is your tree datastructure supposed to work? It is basically unreadable as it is written currently and I can’t work out how your traversal as written corresponds to it.

Answer (score 9):

### Breadth-first search using an agenda

The classic way to do a breadth-first search is by maintaining an *agenda*: a list of things to look at next.  Then you simply peel objects off the start of the agenda, and add their children to the *end* of the agenda.  A very simple-minded approach to such an agenda is a list of nodes: to add to the end of the list you then use `append`.

I can't understand your tree structure (please, when asking questions which need specification of a data structure or an algorithm *give that specification*: it is a waste of everyone's time to try to second-guess this) so I have made my own in terms of lists: a tree is a cons whose car is its value and whose cdr is a list of children.  Here are functions to make and access such a tree structure, and a sample tree.

```
(defun tree-node-value (n)
  (car n))

(defun tree-node-children (n)
  (cdr n))

(defun make-tree-node (value &optional (children '()))
  (cons value children))

(defparameter *sample-tree*
  (make-tree-node
   1
   (list
    (make-tree-node 2 (list (make-tree-node 3)))
    (make-tree-node 4 (list (make-tree-node 5) (make-tree-node 6)))
    (make-tree-node 7 (list (make-tree-node 8 (list (make-tree-node 9))))))))
```

Now I never have to worry about the explicit structure of trees again.

Now here is a function which uses an agenda which will search this tree for a given node value:

```
(defun search-tree/breadth-first (tree predicate)
  ;; search a tree, breadth first, until predicate matches on a node's
  ;; value.  Return the node that matches.
  (labels ((walk (agenda)
             (if (null agenda)
                 ;; we're done: nothing matched
                 (return-from search-tree/breadth-first nil)
               (destructuring-bind (this . next) agenda
                 (if (funcall predicate (tree-node-value this))
                     ;; found it, return the node
                     (return-from search-tree/breadth-first this)
                   ;; missed, add our children to the agenda and
                   ;; carry on
                   (walk (append next (tree-node-children this))))))))
    (walk (list tree))))
```

For comparison here is a depth first search:

```
(defun search-tree/depth-first (tree predicate)
  ;; search a tree, depth first, until predicate matches on a node's
  ;; value
  (labels ((walk (node)
             (if (funcall predicate (tree-node-value node))
                 (return-from search-tree/depth-first node)
               (dolist (child (tree-node-children node) nil)
                 (walk child)))))
    (walk tree)))
```

You can now compare these implementations by having a predicate which prints its argument but always fails, thus causing a traversal of the whole tree:

```
> (search-tree/breadth-first *sample-tree*
                             (lambda (v)
                               (print v)
                               nil))

1 
2 
4 
7 
3 
5 
6 
8 
9 
nil

> (search-tree/depth-first *sample-tree*
                           (lambda (v)
                             (print v)
                              nil))

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
nil
```

---

### Appendix 1: a better agenda implementation

One problem with this naive agenda implementation is that we end up calling `append` all the time.  A cleverer implementation allows items to be appended to the end efficiently.  Here is such an implementation:

```
(defun make-empty-agenda ()
  ;; an agenda is a cons whose car is the list of items in the agenda
  ;; and whose cdr is the last cons in that list, or nil is the list
  ;; is empty.  An empty agenda is therefore (nil . nil)
  (cons nil nil))

(defun agenda-empty-p (agenda)
  ;; an agenda is empty if it has no entries in its list.
  (null (car agenda)))

(defun agenda-next-item (agenda)
  ;; Return the next entry from the agenda, removing it
  (when (agenda-empty-p agenda)
    (error "empty agenda"))
  (let ((item (pop (car agenda))))
    (when (null (car agenda))
      (setf (cdr agenda) nil))
    item))

(defun agenda-add-item (agenda item)
  ;; add an item to the end of the agenda, returning it
  (let ((item-holder (list item)))
    (if (agenda-empty-p agenda)
        (setf (car agenda) item-holder
              (cdr agenda) item-holder)
      (setf (cdr (cdr agenda)) item-holder
            (cdr agenda) item-holder))
    item))
```

Note that there is no way of copying one of these agendas provided.

Here is an explicitly iterative function which uses this 'clever' agenda:

```
(defun search-tree/breadth-first/iterative (tree predicate)
  (loop with agenda = (make-empty-agenda)
        initially (agenda-add-item agenda tree)
        while (not (agenda-empty-p agenda))
        for node = (agenda-next-item agenda)
        when (funcall predicate (tree-node-value node))
        do (return-from search-tree/breadth-first/iterative node)
        else do (loop for c in (tree-node-children node)
                      do (agenda-add-item agenda c))
        finally (return nil)))
```

Finally, any agenda-based search can easily be modified to be restartable: it simply needs to return the current agenda at the point it matched, and allow passing in of an agenda.  Here is a variant of the above function which supports restarting searches:

```
(defun search-tree/breadth-first/iterative (tree predicate 
                                                 &optional (agenda
                                                            (make-empty-agenda)))
  ;; search TREE using PREDICATE.  if AGENDA is given and is not empty
  ;; instead restart using it (TREE is ignored in this case).  Return
  ;; the node found, or nil, and the remaining agenda
  (loop initially (unless (not (agenda-empty-p agenda))
                    (agenda-add-item agenda tree))
        while (not (agenda-empty-p agenda))
        for node = (agenda-next-item agenda)
        when (funcall predicate (tree-node-value node))
        do (return-from search-tree/breadth-first/iterative
             (values node agenda))
        else do (loop for c in (tree-node-children node)
                      do (agenda-add-item agenda c))
        finally (return (values nil agenda))))
```

### Appendix 2: general search with an agenda

It is in fact possible to further generalise the agenda-based approach to searching trees.  In particular:

- if the agenda is a queue (FIFO) then you get breadth-first search;
- if the agenda is a stack (LIFO) then you get depth-first search.

The actual search implementation can be identical for these two cases, which is neat.

Below is some code which demonstrates this.  This defines generic functions for tree access (with methods for cons-based trees) so nothing needs to care about that, and further defines a protocol for agendas with two concrete classes, `queue` and `stack` which have appropriate methods.  The search function is then completely agnostic about whether it does depth-first or breadth-first search, and is restartable in either case.

This is a fairly substantial chunk of code: I'm leaving it here just in case it's useful to anyone.

```
;;;; Trees
;;;

(defgeneric tree-node-value (n)
  (:documentation "The value of a tree node"))

(defgeneric tree-node-children (n)
  (:documentation "The children of a tree"))

;;;; Consy trees
;;;

(defmethod tree-node-value ((n cons))
  (car n))

(defmethod tree-node-children ((n cons))
  (cdr n))

(defun make-cons-tree-node (value &optional (children '()))
  ;; consy trees: I could do some clever EQL method thing perhaps to
  ;; abstract this?
  (cons value children))

(defun form->tree (form &key (node-maker #'make-cons-tree-node))
  (labels ((walk-form (f)
             (destructuring-bind (value . child-forms) f
               (funcall node-maker
                        value
                        (mapcar #'walk-form child-forms)))))
    (walk-form form)))

(defparameter *sample-tree*
  (form->tree '(1 (2 (3))
                  (4 (5) (6))
                   (7 (8 (9))))))


;;;; Agendas
;;;

(defclass agenda ()
  ())

(defgeneric agenda-empty-p (agenda)
  (:documentation "Return true if AGENDA is empty"))

(defgeneric agenda-next-item (agenda)
  (:documentation "Return the next item from AGENDA.
If there is no next item, signal an error: there is a before method which does this.")
  (:method :before ((agenda agenda))
   (when (agenda-empty-p agenda)
     (error "empty agenda"))))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((agenda agenda) &key
                                       (item nil itemp)
                                       (items (if itemp (list item) '()))
                                       (ordered nil))
  (agenda-add-items agenda items :ordered ordered))

(defgeneric agenda-add-item (agenda item)
  (:documentation "Add ITEM to AGENDA, returning ITEM.
There is an around method which arranges for ITEM to be returned.")
  (:method :around ((agenda agenda) item)
   (call-next-method)
   item))

(defgeneric agenda-add-items (agenda items &key ordered)
  (:documentation "Add ITEMS to AGENDA.
If ORDERED is true do so in a way that AGENDA-NEXT-ITEM will pull them
off in the same order.  Return AGENDA (there is an around method which
arranges for this).  The default method just adds the items in the
order given.")
  (:method :around ((agenda agenda) items &key ordered)
   (declare (ignorable ordered))
   (call-next-method)
   agenda)
  (:method ((agenda agenda) items &key ordered)
   (declare (ignorable ordered))
   (loop for item in items
         do (agenda-add-item agenda item))))

;;;; Queues are FIFO agendas
;;;

(defclass queue (agenda)
  ((q :initform (cons nil nil)))
  (:documentation "A queue"))

(defmethod agenda-empty-p ((queue queue))
  (null (car (slot-value queue 'q))))

(defmethod agenda-next-item ((queue queue))
  (let* ((q (slot-value queue 'q))
         (item (pop (car q))))
    (when (null (car q))
      (setf (cdr q) nil))
    item))

(defmethod agenda-add-item ((queue queue) item)
  (let ((q (slot-value queue 'q))
        (item-holder (list item)))
    (if (null (car q))
        (setf (car q) item-holder
              (cdr q) item-holder)
      (setf (cdr (cdr q)) item-holder
            (cdr q) item-holder))))

;;;; Stacks are LIFO agendas
;;;

(defclass stack (agenda)
  ((s :initform '()))
  (:documentation "A stack"))

(defmethod agenda-empty-p ((stack stack))
  (null (slot-value stack 's)))

(defmethod agenda-next-item ((stack stack))
  (pop (slot-value stack 's)))

(defmethod agenda-add-item ((stack stack) item)
  (push item (slot-value stack 's)))

(defmethod agenda-add-items ((stack stack) items &key ordered)
  (loop for item in (if ordered (reverse items) items)
        do (agenda-add-item stack item)))


;;;; Searching with agendas
;;;

(defun tree-search (tree predicate &key (agenda-class 'stack))
  ;; search TREE using PREDICATE.  AGENDA-CLASS (default STACK)
  ;; defines the type of search: a STACK will result in a depth-first
  ;; search while a QUEUE will result in a breadth-first search.  This
  ;; is a wrapper around AGENDA-SEARCH.
  (agenda-search (make-instance agenda-class :item tree) predicate))

(defun agenda-search (agenda predicate)
  ;; Search using an agenda.  PREDICATE is compared against the value
  ;; of a tree node.  On success return the node matched and the
  ;; agenda, on failure return NIL and NIL.  If the returned agenda is
  ;; not empty it can be used to restart the search.
  (loop while (not (agenda-empty-p agenda))
        for node = (agenda-next-item agenda)
        when (funcall predicate (tree-node-value node))
        do (return-from agenda-search
             (values node agenda))
        else do (agenda-add-items agenda (tree-node-children node)
                                  :ordered t)
        finally (return (values nil nil))))
```

Comment: Very instructional! But I think there is a parenthesis missing at the end of `agenda-add-item`.