# Traversing Tree Level by Level (Breadth First) in Lisp

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp, breadth-first-search

I am attempting to print, in order of level, a tree in common Lisp.

The list is `(1 (2 4 (5 (8 11)) 6) (3 (7 9 10)))`, meaning that the tree is ordered:

```
1. 1
2. 2 3
3. 4 5 6 7
4. 8 9 10
5. 11
```

Here is a quick mock up of the tree:

[image]

I am trying to print this tree in this order by performing a breadth first search.

What I have been thinking here is that I should simply be able to `car` and `cdr` my way through this tree, but have been having immense trouble figuring out exactly how to. Here is exactly what I've tried in semi-pseudo code.

```
(defun traverse (*cur-level*)
  (print (car *cur-level*)) ; print out the first element of the current level
    (if (cdr *cur-level*) ; if cdr of next level is not nil
      (setq *next-level* (cdr *cur-level*) ;set that to be the next level
      (traverse *next-level*)) ; recursively call until all levels traversed. 
                               ; else, simply do not do anything and terminate
                               ; the function.
```

Stepping through the tree on my own, I've found that on the *second loop* this algorithm breaks because

```
;first loop
(car *cur-level) = 1
(cdr *cur-level*)=((2 4 (5 (8 11)) 6) (3 (7 9 10)),
```

so on the next loop

```
;second loop
(car *cur-level*) = (2 4 (5 (8 11)) 6)
(cdr *cur-level*) = (3 (7 9 10))
```

This means that the tree essentially splits, and `(2 4 (5 (8 11)) 6)` is ignored.

Also, on the same loop, `(car cur-level)` is not a single element, but a list. Meaning I would need to do:

```
;still second loop
(car (car *cur-level*) = 2
(cdr (car *cur-level*) = (4 (5 (8 11)) 6)
```

So I tried including a condition that checks the size of the level:

```
(if (> (list-length (car *cur-level*)) 1)
  (print (car (car *cur-level*))
  (setq *next-level* (cdr (car *cur-level*))
```

But that does not fix the fact that `(3 (7 9 10)` is separated from the tree, meaning that the order is printing incorrectly, and makes me feel like I am fixing a problem specific to only this tree instead of having a proper algorithm.

Note: this problem happens twice, once on the second loop and another time on the fourth loop of the left side of the tree (where `(car cur-level) = (5 (8 11))`).

How can I do this correctly? I am truly stuck here and have no clue how to continue.

Comment: Don't abuse asterisks ("earmuffs"). They usually indicate a "special" variable, with different scope and binding rules.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from the tree diagram to the list version. What is a tree node in the list?

Comment: @molbnilo Sorry, I didn't know that. I thought it was common practice to do that for every variable because of readability. Will fix in the future.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I was simply using what is in the book. I believe the representation lies on left and right children with no leaves of their own not being in their own list. so `(2 4 (5 (8 11)) 6)` translates to what you see on the tree because 2 is the root, 4 and 6 have no children, and 5 has a child as does 8.

Comment: Shouldn't (7 9 10) be (7 (9 10))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your original code you are trying to do this:

```lisp
(defun traverse (cur-level)
  (print (car cur-level)) ;print out the first element of the current level
  (when (cdr cur-level) ;if cdr of next level is not nil
    (setq next-level (cdr cur-level)) ;set that to be the next level
    (traverse next-level)))
```

I think your tree representation could be made better by making sure all children nodes are lists,

like so: `(1 (2 (4) (5 (8 (11))) (6)) (3 (7 (9) (10)))))`

```lisp
(defun traverse2 (children)
  (when children
    (print (mapcar 'car children)) 
    (traverse2 (apply 'append (mapcar 'cdr children)))))

(defun traverse (tree)
  (print (car tree))
  (traverse2 (cdr tree)))
```

Try running this code [here](https://rextester.com/live/MKEA64267).

I couldn't generalize this much as I am unfamiliar with Common Lisp, but I hope this helps.

**Edit**: ***further explanation***

Remember that the input to traverse2 will always be a list of childnodes (which themselves are lists)

From here on I shall refer to this input list of childnodes as `input`

1. `mapcar 'car` gets the first element of every childnode in `input`
2. `mapcar 'cdr` gets the every other element other than the first element of every childnode in `input`

Now the problem with step 2 is that unlike `car` which pops out a nice non-list element (in this case), `cdr` gives me a list

So a list of lists(or list of child-nodes)  is now transformed to a list of list of lists (or a list of list of childnodes)

3. `apply 'append` flattens this list of list of lists into just a list of lists (or a list of list of childnodes into a list of childnodes)
4. put back output of 2 (list of lists || list of childnodes) into traverse2

Comment: The first snippet still has `next-level` as free variable, and seems wrong: it is just like a `(mapc #'print level)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, this is exactly what I wanted. Could you possibly explain the last two lines of `traverse2`? Stepping through on my own, I found that the in the second loop `(mapcar 'car children)` prints `(2 3)`, and on the next iteration would print (4 5 6 7) but only if `(apply 'append (mapcar 'cdr children)`. What exactly is the `(apply 'append)` doing? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is a near duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974738/breadth-first-search-in-lisp): for any kind of breadth-first traversal of a tree you work using an *agenda*.  [my answer to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987675/5920214) gives a succession of increasingly sophisticated approaches to this problem, starting with a simple-minded listy agenda, and ending up by showing that if you swap in different structures for the agenda you can do different sorts of search, including breadth- & depth-first, with the same code.

First of all *abstract the tree structure*: it's the 1970s already and we don't need code which is full of `car` & `cdr` when it means something else.  Your tree in fact has a somewhat irregular structure since nodes can be conses of (value . children) or just raw values:

```
(defun tree-node-value (node)
  ;; a node is either (value . children) or value
  (typecase node
    (cons
     (car node))
    (t node)))

(defun tree-node-children (node)
  ;; a node only has children if it is a cons
  (typecase node
    (cons
     (cdr node))
    (t '())))

(defun make-tree-node (value children)
  ;; only make consy nodes
  (cons value children))
```

I haven't bothered to make a builder, but I'll just define your sample tree:

```
(defparameter *sample-tree* '(1 (2 4 (5 (8 11)) 6) (3 (7 9 10))))
```

And now here is an implementation of a function which will walk a visitor over trees in breadth-first order, using a simple-minded listy agenda:

```
(defun walk-tree/breadth-first (tree visitor)
  ;; walk over a tree breadth-first, calling visitor on each node's
  ;; value, using an agenda represented explicitly as a list.
  (labels ((walk (agenda)
             (when (not (null agenda))
               ;; there is more to do
               (destructuring-bind (this . next) agenda
                 ;; call the visitor
                 (funcall visitor (tree-node-value this))
                 ;; and continue with the extended agenda
                 (walk (append next (tree-node-children this)))))))
    (walk (list tree))
    (values)))
```

And we can call this on your tree, using `print` as the visitor:

```
> (walk-tree/breadth-first *sample-tree* #'print)

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11
```

I'd encourage you to look at the other implementations in the older answer, in particular the explicitly iterative ones.